# Change divider color on DataRow only for rows and not for heading

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to change the divider color in a DataRow in a DataTable, only for the rows and not for the header row.

I can wrap the DataTable in a Theme widget to change the color

```
Center(
  child: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.grey),
    child: DataTable(columns: [
       DataColumn(
       //....
```

but this affects also the headingRow

is there a way to prevent this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the default DataTable because DataTable uses the same Divider for every row including the header row.

But if it is really necessary, I have changed a little bit of code in the `data_table.dart` file that defines DataTable. this will get you what you want although changing the library files is not good practice:

Add this instead of line 893 - 909:

```
final BorderSide borderSide = Divider.createBorderSide(
    context,
    color: Colors.red, // Add this color for your data rows.
    width: dividerThickness
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.dividerThickness
      ?? _dividerThickness,
);
final BorderSide borderSide2 = Divider.createBorderSide( // Adding this divider for the header row.
    context,
    color: Colors.blue, // The color of your header row divider.
    width: dividerThickness
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.dividerThickness
      ?? _dividerThickness,
);
final Border? border = showBottomBorder
    ? Border(bottom: borderSide)
    : index == 0 ? null : index == 1 ? Border(top: borderSide2) : Border(top: borderSide); // Changed this that the first row uses the other divider.
```

The result:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAKST.jpg)

Comment: And now do i use it for data rows, without it affecting the heading?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question and now I get it. So I think this is not possible because data table uses the same divider for every row including the header row. I will edit my answer now.